# IPMI IKVM + External display on Supermicro X11SBA-F?

Tags: ipmi

I've been thinking of getting X11SBA-F for to replace my aging operator machine, but it must be hooked to a monitor 24/7, and at the same time i want IPMI IKVM to be active as well. Otherwise, i'd rather get consumer motherboard without IPMI.

Problem is, my previous experience with X11SCA-F indicates it's not possible to have IPMI IKVM + active external display at the same time.

This is the result of my experiment of X11SCA-F + viewsonic monitor 2407h which has both hdmi and vga output, the cpu is i5-8400t

Internal graphics enabled

- Primary display Auto + hdmi monitor = hdmi ok, ikvm blackscreen
- Primary display auto + vga monitor = vga black screen, ikvm ok
- Primary display igfx + hdmi monitor = hdmi ok, ikvm blackscreen
- Primary display igfx + vga monitor = vga blackscreen, ikvm ok
- Primary display PEG + hdmi monitor = hdmi ok, ikvm blackscreen
- Primary display PEG + vga monitor = vga black screen, ikvm ok
- Primary display PCI + hdmi monitor = hdmi blackscreen, ikvm ok
- Primary display PCI + vga monitor = vga black screen, ikvm ok
- Primary display SG + hdmi monitor = hdmi ok, ikvm blackscreen
- Primary display SG + vga monitor = vga black screen, ikvm ok

So is this really a limitation of IKVM, or am i missing something here?
Or maybe it only applies to X11SCA-F?

Edit : apparently Mouse + keyboard input works during blackscreen

Comment: Usually you need one or other...  In case you really need this kind of approach, why not to focus to external "rack mounted KVM" with network interface? You can manage even more devices including any other devices with graphical output...

Comment: Does it require kvm switch? Might consider that but since mouse keyboard works during blackscreen IKVM i thought there might be a workaround. I'd rather keep minimal number of devices too anyway

Comment: My option require kvm switch (could be 1U device - with or without monitor included).
I have no idea about your device so I have post this just as comment and not answer.... I hope somebpdy will help you or you would find it out ;).